# How to get woocommerce subscriptions list?

Tags: list, woocommerce, product, subscriptions

I want to get list of all subscriptions in the WOOcommerce products.

Is there a **built-in** function or i have to use `WP_QUERY` thing to access that particular thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `WC_Subscriptions::get_subscriptions()`.

Parameters for customising the output are documented in the function's doc block.